Manually connect Mac to a Bluetooth audio device when it’s paired with several devices
I'm connecting to a Bluetooth audio device (Google buds) 4 devices:

2x MacBook pro (Sonoma)
1x Google Pixel 7
Sony TV

Let's say I'm playing some audio on one of MacBooks. Suddenly I get a call on the phone.
I stop the audio on the MacBook and take the call.
After the call I want to switch back to the audio of the MacBook. But it takes a long time until the audio plays through.
On other times the second MacBook "steals" the connection  even though it's on sleep and the lid is closed. ‍♂️
Tl;dr: how can I make the MacBook get back the connection to the audio device manually?

You can manually set the sound input and output device on your MBP. Just go to  > System Settings > Sound and choose the output or the input device you need.
An easier way to access the sound settings could be to have the sound control in the menu bar all the time. To do that, go to  > System Settings > Control Center. Then, click the pop-up menu next to Sound on the right, then choose whether to show Sound in the menu bar all the time.

This works. Although I sometimes have to set the audio device to the Mac speakers first and then back to the Bluetooth device.
